# Is there a way to write a regular expression for leex and yecc that matches the regex literals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, erlang, yacc, lex

I'm trying to write a javascript parser in erlang using leex and yecc, and I can't figure out how to match a regex literal. Regex literals are surrounded by forward slash characters on either side, but if a forward slash is inside a class, or in parentheses then it's not counted as the end of the regex literal.

Just using the obvious: `/.*/` doesn't work because that matches things beyond the end of the regex if there's something with another forward slash after it. Attempting to use character classes that exclude forward slashes except in character classes and parentheses (like `/(\\.|[^/\\]|\[(^\]/])*])*/`) just leads to complicated regexes that still don't work.

Is it even possible to do this? I thought that lex and yacc could be used for parsing anything, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: You can't do it with lex alone because regular expressions can contain parenthesised subexpressions with an arbitrary nesting level, and that's not a regular grammar. You can do it with lex and yacc, in the usual way: define an expression grammar and have at it. (Although there are lots of irritating little corner cases, like trying to figure out under what circumstances a `]` actually ends a character class, which in part depends on which regular expression dialect you are trying to recognise.)

Comment: @rici Would I need to be able to have lex switch states to do that? Erlang's lex implementation doesn't seem to support having multiple states.

Comment: I use lex states to correctly tokenise character classes. But it's not absolutely necessary, I think. You could do the work in the parser, at the cost of some extra complication of the grammar. It's often possible to put the work into the grammar instead of using lexical states.

Comment: OK, I took a look at the Erlang parse tools module, and I don't see lexical states. But I don't think that's very important; you can use the generated `token` function yourself. The manual assumes you'll be using an I/O file, which I think is a bit presumptive; if you are, then you can wrap `token` in a `get_until` request, as indicated. Otherwise, you'll have to find a way to wrap a character string as an I/O server, or to handle the leex:token function's calling convention yourself. Despite the manual's claim that it's not intended to be called by you, it doesn't look too hard to me.

Comment: The key is that you can use a different lexer on each call to `token`. So you only have to figure out how to sequence them. For example, you could use the module containing the generated lexer as the lexer state, and include the next module as part of the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Leex require that regular expressions used in it are "true regular expressions" (PCRE allows matching broader set of languages). Regular expression description language is itself not a regular language, which mean that no single regular expression can match the regular expression definition language.

What you can do, is that you can tokenise the language into separate individual tokens via Leex, and then parse them using Yecc.